# ionic 3 EmailValidator usage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, email-validation

I'm using newest ionic framework and I see that angular dev team added `EmailValidator` feature. But it's a little bit unclear how I should use it. Can anybody give me an example of usage?

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>

    <ion-list>

        <ion-item margin-vertical>
            <ion-label>Enter email</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>

    <button (type)="button" ion-button block large [disabled]="!email" (click)="checkValidation()">Check!</button>

</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EmailValidator } from '@angular/forms';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
     selector: 'page-login',
     templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class LoginPage  {
    email: string;

    constructor() {}

    checkValidation() : string () {
        // validation here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think you'd want to use a form, and seems you want to use a template driven form. So let's add the form tags, as well as what we need to register form controls and be able to check and display potential form errors, so that we can get rid of that `checkValidation` method that is then totally redundant! :)

We need to add the form tags, we can also skip the variable `email` if you do not need it for something else. The object the form produces would contain that variable.

We need to use `name` attribute and `ngModel` so that we can register it as a form control. Then we need template reference and `ngModel` to be able to inspect the controls state, i.e is it valid or not? Then we add the actual email pattern validation by marking `email` to the input field:

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
  <ion-item margin-vertical>
    <ion-label>Enter email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" name="email" #email="ngModel" ngModel email></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button block large [disabled]="!f.valid" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

With error messages and disabling sumbit button can be done in many ways, and when to display error messages, e.g when form is `dirty`,`touched` and so on. Here we could show error message if the email is not valid by doing `f.hasError('email','email')`.

**DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/xJVK2ZtyiQ055tEAA2F0?p=preview